# Set where $f$ is discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis

I have several problems identifying where a function is, or not is continuous.

For example: Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$$ f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        1, & \text{for } x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
        0, &  \text{otherwise}\\
        \end{array}\right.
$$
 and $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
$$ g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        1/q, & \text{for } x = p/q\\
        0, &  \text{otherwise}\\
        \end{array}\right.$$
where $p,q$ are positive and co-primes.

How can I identify on these examples and others where the function is continuous and where is not?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: **Hint:** For $f(x)$ this should be easy for you. (If not, then don't bother with $g(x)$ until it is.) For $g(x)$ there should be some points where it's clear there is a discontinuity, so focus on the other points -- maybe by picking one of these other points and thinking about what the graph looks like near the point you chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function is called the *dirichlet function* or the *characteristic function for $\mathbb{Q}$*. It is discontinuous everywhere. For example: let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. Let $x \in [0,1]$. Can you find a $\delta>0$ so that $|y-x|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$? No, because for every real number, there is a rational *and* irrational number within $\delta$ of it. In other words, the real numbers are the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, or in other words: $\mathbb{Q}$ is said to be **Dense** in $\mathbb{R}$.

For this reason, for all $x \in [0,1]$ you can find some $y \in [0,1]$ so that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|=1$. This implies discontinuous.

The second example is much stranger. It is discontinuous at all rationals, and continuous at all irrationals. I'll provide a hint for the proof that it is continuous for every irrational $c$:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\frac{1}{m}<\epsilon$. However, there are only finitely many rational numbers with a denominator $m$ or smaller (in lowest terms.)

Let $q_1,...q_k \in [0,1]$ enumerate these rationals. Let $\delta=\textrm{min}\{|c-q_1|,...|c-q_n|\}$

Suppose that $x \in [0,1]$ and that $|x-c|<\delta$. There are two cases.

As far as intuition goes, the first function is very clearly everywhere discontinuous for the reason I gave. For the second one, it is a bit more pathological, and in my opinion it's a pretty good motivation for defining continuity rigorously. The reason this function is continuous at the irrationals depends critically on the fact that there were finitely many rationals with denominator less than $m$.

In fact, (it is slightly more difficult to show) there is no function $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $g$ is continuous for the rationals, and discontinuous at the irrationals! Very strange, you can try to prove it for yourself.

Comment: Actually, as the OP defined $g(x),$ there is one rational number at which $g(x)$ is continuous --- $x=0.$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was very clarifying. I will think about it.